# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int', for extract_image_patches

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using extract_image_patches for my image dataset which has dynamic dimensions.

I am getting following error log :

```
 array_grad.py", line 604, in _ExtractImagePatchesGrad     rows_out = int(ceil(rows_in / stride_r))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I tried using

1) **image.set_shape** method

2) image **resizing_using_crop_or_pad** to avoid it, but still the error persists.

**Update1**: Following is the code snippet

```
#######
#shape=[batch_size,height,width, target_size2

out_processed_model2 =tf.reshape(out_processed2, shape = [tf.shape(image_patch_tf2)[0], tf.shape(image_patch_tf2)[1], tf.shape(image_patch_tf2)[2], target_size2]) 

#PostProcessing

as0, as1, as2, as3, as4, as5= tf.split(out_processed_model2, target_size, 0)
out_model2_batch_to_depth = tf.concat([as0, as1, as2, as3, as4, as5],3)
#Model-3 Preprocessing

s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15,s16, s17, s18, s19= tf.split(out_model2_batch_to_depth , target_size2, 3)
A_3= tf.concat([s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15,s16, s17, s18, s19],1)
out_model2_depth_to_batch=tf.reshape(A_3, [tf.shape(image_patch_tf2)[0]*target_size2, tf.shape(image_patch_tf2)[1], tf.shape(image_patch_tf2)[2], 1])
############################Model -3#######################
stride_h3= 2
stride_w3 = 4
cell3 = 50
target_size3 = 80
input_size3 =stride_h3*stride_w3
image_patch_tf3 = tf.extract_image_patches(images = out_model2_depth_to_batch, ksizes = [1, stride_h3, stride_w3, 1], strides = [1, stride_h3, stride_w3, 1], rates = [1,1,1,1], padding="SAME", name="Extract_Image_Patches3")
```

Comment: It seems rows_in is None, not the value you think. Check it.

Comment: I tried accessing the image_data dimension. I am able to see the shape of it as [1, 144,144, 1]. Row size is 144 in that case. But its throwing the same error.

Comment: The problem isn't with image_data. Try this line immediately before line 604: 'print (rows_in)'. The output won't be what you think. We can't help you with more details unless you actually post your code.

Comment: DO u think its a bug or else?? I tried with different methods but getting the same error :(

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I'm getting the same error!

Comment: Hi, The problem is because it is expected to specify the shape of the image which we are giving to tf.extract_image_patches(). Couldnt resolve so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, you're trying to use `NoneType` for `rows_in`. This likely means however you're setting this variable is incorrect.

The error message tells you precisely what's going on. `unsupported operand type(s) for /` tells you that whatever is causing the error is happening in your division. The two types it gives you afterwards, `NoneType` and `int` tell you the types of the two variables that are being used with that operation. Since you cannot divide none by int, an error occurs.